# Why the prediction of multivariate GARCH is just a line?

Tags: prediction, garch

I'm doing multivariate GARCH analysis between two stocks, like many examples you can find online. The fitting goes very well but I'm confused by the prediction part. 
Why the forecasted conditional covariance is a straight line 
and why the fitted and forecast of the VaR plot is also a straight line? 
If this is what it should be, how about the explanation? 
Here is part of the code and VaR plot from `R`. Thanks.

```
uspec.n = multispec(replicate(2, ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)),distribution.model = "norm")))
spec.dccn = dccspec(uspec.n, dccOrder = c(1, 1),model="DCC", distribution ='mvnorm')
dcc.fit<-dccfit(spec.dccn, data =SOTS[,c(6,7)])
plot(dcc.fit)
fitdcc=dccfit(spec.dccn, data=SOTS[,c(6,7)], out.sample = 1000, solver = "nlminb", solver.control =
                list(),fit.control = list(eval.se = TRUE, stationarity = TRUE, scale = FALSE),cluster = NULL, fit =
                NULL, VAR.fit = NULL)
plot(fitdcc)

fc1=dccforecast(dcc.fit, n.ahead = 50, n.roll = 0)
plot(fc1)
```

[image]

Comment: You did not show the results of `plot(dcc.fit)`, `fitdcc=dccfit...` and `plot(fitdcc)` but only show that of `plot(fc1)`, right? Anf you are concerned only about the latter one? Then the three commands before `plot(fc1)` are not relevant for this question. (Just trying to see if I get the question correctly.) By the way, aren't you plotting the conditional mean as opposed to the conditional variance or covariance? Since your conditional mean model is empty, it *should* be a straight line. That could be an answer explaining what is happening in the picture.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes, you are right, I just want to try 'n.roll=1000' to see if there is any difference. So how can I specify the conditional mean model? I thought it was done by command 'model="DCC"'.Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, I suggest you delete the redundant code lines. Second, in `ugarchspec` you have the argument `mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0))`, which tells the conditional mean model is just a constant (no AR, no MA parts). You can modify that argument to get a non-constant conditional mean model of ARMA type. You can also add external regressors with an appropriate argument, that will yield ARMAX.

Comment: @RichardHardy Oh! I see. I messed it up with `garchOrder = c(1, 1)`. Thank you very much.